# Storing flags in SQL column, and indexing them

Tags: sql, multi-database

I need to store a set of flags that are related to an entity into database. `Flags` might not be the best word because these are not binary information (on/off), but rather a to-be-defined set of codes.

Normally, you would store each information (say each flag value) in a distinct column, but I'm exploring opportunities for storing such information in data structures different than one-column-for-each-attribute to prevent a dramatic increase in column mappings. Since each flag is valid for each attribute of an entity, you understand that for large entities that **intrinsically** require a large number of columns the total number of columns may grow as 2n.

Eventually, these codes can be mapped to a positional string.

I'm thinking about something like: `02A` not being interpreted as `dec 42` but rather as:

- Flag 0 in position 1 (or zero if you prefer...)
- Flag 2 in position 2
- Flag A in position 3

Data formatted in such a way can be easily processed by high-level *programming* languages, because PL/SQL is out of the scope of the question and all these values are supposed to be processed by Java.

### Now the real problem

One of my specs is to optimize searching. I have been required to find a way (say, an efficient way) to seek for entities that show a certain flag (or a special `0` flag) in a given position.

Normally, in SQL, given the RDBMS-specific substring function, you would

```
SELECT * FROM ENTITIES WHERE SUBSTRING(FLAGS,{POSITION},1) = {VALUE};
```

This works, but I'm afraid it may be a little slow on all platforms but Oracle, which, AFAIK, supports creating secondary indexes mapped to a substring.

However, my solution **must** work in MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server and DB2 thanks to Hibernate.

Given such a design, is there some, possibly cross-platform, indexing strategy that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If performance is an issue I would go for a some different model here.

Say a table that store entities and a relation 1->N to another table (say: flags table: entId(fk), flag, position) and this table would have an index on flag and position.

The issue here would be to get this flags in a simple column wich can be done in java or even on the database (but it would be difficult to have a cross plataform query to this)

Comment: The first design had such a one-to-many mapping with these flags, but when there are 200 millions of records for the main entity type that table is going to be huge. Not actually hitting the 64-bit cap for LONG, but I'm seeking for a way to save "a little" space (though a 32 bit array stores "only" 32 flags for each entity and adds an extra 800Mb to the table)

Comment: In that previous design each flag was identified by a *name*, coded as a *string*, or even better, a *varchar(200)*

Comment: Is this table (flags) going to always grow? Because if it won't I don't see a problem with 800Mb of data. That is the best you can do for performance (because of your cross plataform requirement). And just curious about it, what kind of problem will have more than 200 millions registries ?!

Comment: It's generally not supposed to grow. Growing and shrinking are rare events

Comment: I misunderstood my boss: the records are in the range of 20 millions, and are demographic information

Comment: Well I stick to the info I provided you (even if it was 200 millions). The best approach is to have 1-N relation so you can index that info. It will be incredibly fast to search on indexed field. like `flag = {VALUE} and position = {POS}` specially if it will not have null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a database-independent, reasonable method for storing such flags, then use typical SQL data types.  For a binary flag, you can use `bit` or `boolean` (this differs among databases).  For other flags, you can use `tinyint` or `smallint`.

Doing bit-fiddling is *not* going to be portable.  If nothing else, the functions used to extract particular bits from data differ among databases.

Second, if performance is an issue, then you may need to create indexes to avoid full table scans.  You can create indexes on normal SQL data types (although some databases may not allow indexes on bits).

It sounds like you are trying to be overly clever.  You should first get the application to work using reasonable data structures.  Then you will understand where the performance issues are and can work on fixing them.

Comment: `bit` is *not* a "typical SQL data type". The "standard" type for a flag would be `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

I have improved my design and performed a **benchmark** and found an interesting result.

I created a dummy demographic entity with first/last name columns, birthdate, birthplace, email, SSN...

#### Then in version 1

I added a column `VALIDATION VARCAHR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL` with an index on it.

Instead of positional flags, the new column contains an *unordered* set of **codes** each representing a specific format error (e.g. `A01` means "last name not specified", etc.). Each code is terminated by a colon `:` symbol.

Example columns look like

```
NULL
'A01:A03:A10:'
'A05:'
```

Typical queries are:

```
SELECT * FROM ENTITIES WHERE VALIDATION IS {NOT} NULL
```

Search for entities that are valid/invalid (`NULL` = no problem)

```
SELECT * FROM ENTITIES WHERE VALIDATION LIKE '%AXX:';
```

Selects entities with a specific problem

#### Then in version 1

I added a column `VALID TINYINT NOT NULL` with an index which is `0=invalid`, `1=valid` (Hibernate maps a `Boolean` to a `TINYINT` in MySQL).

I added a lookup table

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITY_VALIDATION (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PERSON_ID LONG NOT NULL, --REFERENCES PERSONS(ID) --Omitted for performance
    ERROR CHAR(3) NOT NULL
)
```

With index on both `PERSON_ID` and `ERROR`. This represents the `1:N` relationship

Queries:

```
SELECT * FROM ENTITIES WHERE VALIDATION = {0|1}
```

Select invalid/valid entities

```
SELECT * FROM ENTITIES JOIN ENTITY_VALIDATION ON ENTITIES.ID = ENTITY_VALIDATION.PERSON_ID WHERE ERROR = 'Axx';
```

Selects entities with a given problem

### Then I benchmarked

the count(*) function via JUnit+JDBC. So the same queries you see above replace `*` with `COUNT(*)`.

I did several benchmarks, with entity table containing 100k, 250k, 500k, 750k, 1M entities with a mean ratio `entity:flag` of `1:3` (there are meanly 3 errors for each entity).

### The result

is displayed below. While correct/incorrect entities lookup is equally performing, it looks like MySQL is faster in the `LIKE` operator rather than in a `JOIN`, even though there are indexes

[image: Excel graph]

### Of course,

This was only a benchmark on MySQL. While the approach is cross-platform, the benchmark does **not** (yet) compare performance in different DBMSes